# App crashing because of glGetString

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, nsstring

I am running cocos2d-iphone 1.0.0 and following [this](http://www.tinytimgames.com/2011/07/22/cocos2d-and-arc/) tutorial to use cocos2d with ARC.  Unfortunately, I am getting a 'SIGABRT' crash error whenever I try to add a TMX Tiled Map to a CCLayer.  I have traced this problem down to the `-(BOOL)checkForGLExtension:(NSString *)searchName`, and even further to within this function to `NSString *extensionsString = [NSString stringWithCString:glExtensions encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];`

Here is the checkForGLExtension function:

```
- (BOOL) checkForGLExtension:(NSString *)searchName {
// For best results, extensionsNames should be stored in your renderer so that it does not
// need to be recreated on each invocation.
NSLog(@"%@", glExtensions);
NSString *extensionsString = [NSString stringWithCString:glExtensions encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", extensionsString);
NSArray *extensionsNames = [extensionsString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; }
```

The `encoding:` part of `NSString *extensionsString = [NSString stringWithCString:glExtensions encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];`is probably making the application crash.  I am also receiving NULL in my logs for `GL_VENDOR`, `GL_VERSION`, `GL_RENDERER`, and even `glExtensions`.

Looking back at gl.h in the OpenGLES.framework shows me this:

```
/* StringName */
#define GL_VENDOR                         0x1F00
#define GL_RENDERER                       0x1F01
#define GL_VERSION                        0x1F02
#define GL_EXTENSIONS                     0x1F03
```

In which all of them are NULL.

Comment: by the way, also using Xcode 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOTE: I have no idea about iOS development :)

Getting NULL from glGetString usually means that the OpenGL context is not bound or was created incorrectly. You should check that. Also check for GL error with glGetError.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately if I call glGetError after the problem-causing code line, the application does not have time to return glGetError.  Asking for it before returns NULL...

Comment: Thanks!!  This actually turned out to be the answer.  Apparently, I needed to set up an EAGLView and attach that with my CCLayer's node function.  Thanks you again!

Comment: Can you please provide your code? I am stuck on the same problem.