# Fail to start project from NetBeans on Mac

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I have switched from PC to Mac, and I have a problem with Netbeans (last version, with 1.7 JDK).

When I run the project in NetBeans, it won't launch and I get this error:

> Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable
>   core dumping, try "-ulimit -c unlimited" before starting java again

*But*, if in NetBeans I make a "Clean and Build project", and then I launch it from the Finder, it works.

I don't understand. Do I need to parameter somethin, and as a Mac beginner, where to do it? I found others topics where people had the same problem, but didn't find a solution.

EDIT:

The complete report:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff8874b97a, pid=932, tid=36619
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b12
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libGL.dylib+0x197a]  glGetString+0xf
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/Eric/NetBeansProjects/GCW/hs_err_pid932.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
# Java Result: 134 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)"
```

Comment: Please, write error, which was before the "Failed to write core dump..."

Comment: maybe you need more exception handling and are ignoring an exception now (silently repressing it). if you log it then you might know the root cause

Comment: OK, found the origin of the problem : VMWare.
It doesn't happen on my "true" office Mac.

Comment: ... see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047622/app-crashing-because-of-glgetstring At a guess the GLContext is invalid on VMWare